# Convert Array of Strings to Boolean List in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections, boolean

How can I convert Array of Strings into Boolean ArrayList in Java?

*For ex: I have String Array like this:*

```
String[] strs= {"true","false","false","true",..etc};
```

Now, I want all of the above values into a Boolean ArrayList.

```
List<Boolean> bools=[true, false, false, true, ..etc]
```

I can do something like this below, but I want this task to be accomplished in one single line of code.

```
String[] strs={"true","false","false","true",..etc};
List<Boolean> bools=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
for(String x:strs) 
    bools.add(Boolean.parseBoolean(x));
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a single line of code? And what "single line of code" mean? `for(String x:strs) bools.add(Boolean.parseBoolean(x));` is a single line....

Comment: Do you need this change without any for loop ?

Comment: If you are using java-8 use streams to achieve it..but it also does the same ,but looks as single line

Comment: yes, without any loops. Something like, `Arrays.asList(strs);` for String array to ArrayList of Strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use streams with java8

## Example:

```
final String[] stringArray = { "true", "false", "true", etc };
final Boolean[] booleanArray = Arrays.stream(stringArray).map(Boolean::parseBoolean).toArray(Boolean[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(booleanArray));
```

Comment: Is it not possible in Java 7? For ex, BooleanUtils of Apache Commons.?